# How to extract the differential equation of a spiral in polar co-ordinates?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polar-coordinates

[image: Explaining Picture]

Think above picture in polar coordinates. **Q** is the angle, and radius '**r**' is a function of '**Q**'. Now in my problem, radius **r** takes it's minimum value on **Q** = 0 and as **Q** getting bigger, radius **r** is getting biggr as well. But, I'm trying to arrange it's inrease for a predetermined condition. To do that, I have to determine the function of radius **r** over **Q**. The condition is like this:

You see in above picture, There are 3 radiuses. First one is r(0) which is a constant. Second one is r(Q1) and third one is r(Q2). Now, what I need is, when angle Q1 goes to zero (Q1 -> 0), r(Q1) must be equal to a length that

$$ \lim_{Q1 \to 0} \dfrac{(r(Q1)-\dfrac{r(0)}{\cos(Q1)})\times \cos(Q1)}{r(Q1)\times  \sin(Q1)} = \tan(Q\Delta) $$

just like for $ Q2-Q1 = Qx $

$$ \lim_{Qx \to 0}\, \dfrac{(r(Q2)-\dfrac{r(Q1)}{\cos(Qx)})\times \cos(Qx)}{r(Q2)\times  \sin(Qx)} = \tan(Q\Delta) $$

$ Q\Delta $ here is an initial condition, a constant.

I hope I could explain the idea. The result ought to be something like this:

[image: Result]

So obviously the function of **r** must be a differential equation. But I could not figure out the equation so could you please help me with that? It also would be a great example for engineering because in class we always begin from the equation and finish with the graph, but in this, we extract the equation from a given condition.

Comment: Changed for readability. Pl feel free to rollback if felt not alright. It may not be an elliptic curve?

Comment: @Narasimham I could not find the right term to define it but what would you suggest instead of 'elliptical'?

Comment: A spiral in (polar co-ordinates)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geometric construction gives the radius progression as 
$$
r(Q_{k+1})\cos(Q_{k+1}-Q_k)-r(Q_k) = r(Q_{k+1})·  \sin(Q_{k+1}-Q_k)\tan(Q\Delta)
\\~\\\iff\\~\\
r(Q_{k+1})= \frac{r(Q_k)}{\cos(Q_{k+1}-Q_k)-\sin(Q_{k+1}-Q_k)\tan(Q\Delta)}
$$
Assuming the angles are equally spaced, $Q_k=kA$ with some small $A$, then
$$
\cos(A)-\sin(A)\tan(Q\Delta)=1-2\sin(A/2)(\sin(A/2)+\cos(A/2)\tan(Q\Delta))
$$
which approximately reduces to 
$$
=1-A\tan(Q\Delta)+O(A^2)=e^{-A\tan(Q\Delta)+O(A^2)}
$$
giving
$$
r(Q_k)=r(0)e^{(kA)(\tan(Q\Delta)+O(A))}
$$
so that in the limit $A\to 0$ you get the [logarithmic spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_spiral)
$$
r(Q)=r(0)e^{Q·\tan(Q\Delta)}
$$

Comment: I think you made a mistake ;$$ r(Q_{k+1}) =  r(Q_k) \times \dfrac{1}{cos(Q_{k+1} - Q_{k}) - sin(Q_{k+1} - Q_{k})tan{QΔ}}   $$ is the correct formula

Comment: You are right. Only for small arguments is $\sin(QΔ)\approx \tan(QΔ)$.

Comment: how does it change the result of the equation? I dont think it will become e^(smt) now.

Comment: It still is a spiral, the only thing changed is the replacement of $\sin(QΔ)$ by $\tan(QΔ)$. If you join similar triangles in the given fashion, one point at the center, the opposite edges lining up to form a curve, you will always get an exponential spiral.